# How can I get SvelteKit asset path in SCSS variables file?

Tags: sass, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm building a webapp with SvelteKit to deploy to GitLab Pages. As part of the setup, I have to set the `paths.base` value in `svelte.config.json`. In the `app.html`, this path is parsed using `%sveltekit.assets%` and in `.svelte` files this path is parsed with `assets` imported from `$app/paths`.

I also need to set the `$mdi-font-path` in my `variables.scss` - how can I import the asset path in here? I guess there's some form of Vite configuration I can use, but I can't find any examples.

Thanks